# Steps to integrate lightswitch app into existing web application

Tags: .net, web-applications, visual-studio-lightswitch

can anyone tell me step-by-step procedure to deploy lightswitch app into existing web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can find step by step procedure to integrate light switch into existing web application [here](http://www.gyanportal.com/article/step-to-deploy-light-switch-application-in-to-exit/5)

Answer (score 3):

1. Publish the entire Lightswitch app to another web site on the web server.
2. Create an iframe, pointing to the web page hosting the Lighswitch Silverlight app, in the web application.